# WPF GetTemplateChild returns NULL after part renamed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have some code as follows:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "okButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "cancelButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
public class ModalPopup : ContentControl, IModalPopup
{
     private Button _okButton;
     private Button _cancelButton;

     '
     '
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        LoadTemplateParts();
    }

    private void LoadTemplateParts()
    {
        _okButton = GetTemplateChild("okButton") as Button;
        _cancelButton = GetTemplateChild("cancelButton") as Button;
    }

}
```

There are many other template parts defined, though I'm only showing 2, and they all work fine. However if I try to add a new part (i.e. I want to add an Apply Button) the GetTemplateChild method only ever returns null for this new part. It's as though there is a cached definition for these template parts and I need to clean it somehow!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of not wasting someone's valuable time:-

This was an area I was new to and on revisiting after some time had passed I wanted a new Button - however I only created the new attribute and code - I had completely forgotten that I needed to add the new Button to the 'Style' definition for my popup - doh!